# wp_enqueue_script - Additional Jquery Does Not Appear in Source Code

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am able to put bootstrap.min.js with dependency on the native wordpress jquery, but Jquery 1.11.1 does not appear in the source code and Font Awesome also does not work correctly

I've tried some code from other questions in stackoverflow, but I still can not resolve my question

I put some comments in the code below:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
function enqueue_jquery() {
     // deregister jquery ok 
     wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // unregister the WP-provided jQuery   version

    // tag is not added in code
wp_enqueue_script(
    'jquery',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js',
    array(), // don't make jquery dependent on jquery...!
    '1.11.1',
    true
);

} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery');

function enqueue_styles_scripts() {

    //its OK
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'style-theme',
        get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array('bootstrap-css')
    );

    //its OK
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'bootstrap-css',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    );

    //its OK
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'stylish-portfolio',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/othercss.css'
    );

 //I changed the directory of the files to css and fonts folders and it worked correctly
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'font-awesome',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css'

    ); 


    //Appears in header but is working correctly
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'bootstrap-js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',null
    );


} 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles_scripts');


//Its Ok    
function wpse_ie_conditional_scripts() { ?>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_ie_conditional_scripts' );

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve without using function to unregister the native wordpress jquery and register my theme jquery

```
    //Without using function
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', false, '1.11.1');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        function enqueue_styles_scripts() {

            //its OK
            wp_enqueue_style(
                'style-theme',
                get_stylesheet_uri(),
                array('bootstrap-css')
            );

            //its OK
            wp_enqueue_style(
                'bootstrap-css',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css'
            );

            //its OK
            wp_enqueue_style(
                'stylish-portfolio',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/othercss.css'
            );

        //its OK
            wp_enqueue_style(
                'font-awesome',
                get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css'

            ); 


           //its OK
            wp_enqueue_script(
                'bootstrap-js',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js',null
            );


        } 
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles_scripts');


        //Its Ok    
        function wpse_ie_conditional_scripts() { ?>
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
                <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
            <?php
        }
        add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_ie_conditional_scripts' );

        ?>
```

Comment: Are you saying this works? You are still unregistering jQuery - just outside the WP hooks... I also notice you removed the jquery requirement for bootstrap.min.js - that definitely will not work wince bootstrap *does* require jquery... `wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'));` ?

Comment: Yes its works for me, added to source code `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/js/jquery.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>` and `Bootstrap.min.js` is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that 'jquery' is already registered and queued by WP. What I have done in the past is first unregister the WP-provided jquery, and then enqueue my own version. *WARNING: test this out thoroughly, because you will now be upgrading jQuery for the whole WP installation!*

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery'); // unregister the WP-provided jQuery version
wp_enqueue_script(
    'jquery',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js',
    array(), // don't make jquery dependent on jquery...!
    '1.11.1',
    true
);
```

Alternatively, you could load a *second* version of jQuery in no-conflicts mode, but that is not a really good idea...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying, the code unregistered the native wordpress jquery but it is not yet registering the jquery that is in my project folder

Comment: Hmmm - really? I've edited my answer, changed `null` for `array()` as the dependencies, but that shouldn't make a difference... So the script tag is not added to your page's source at all? Or it is but is not loading? (error 404)

Comment: The function is not adding the jquery in the code, in the console is appearing these errors `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
     At bootstrap.min.js: 6
VM48: 402` and  `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
     At VM48: 402 `

Comment: Ok. Sorry to state the obvious but... You have removed the dependency, right? `..., array(), '1.11.1', true);` And of course the file `get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js'` exists?

Comment: Yes, I did. Please, see the updated code in my question, I followed your guidelines

Comment: And yes directory `/js/jquery.js` exist, Is in the same folder as `/js/bootstrap.min.js`